# How do I get the node type label from a node object?

Tags: 8, entities

I'm trying to get the bundle label (node type label) of the node from a node object in Drupal 8.

This works, but seems long-winded:

```
$node_type = \Drupal::entityManager()->getStorage('node_type')->load($node->getType())->get('name');
```

Is there another way to get the bundle label, possible in a *less complicated* way?

Comment: `$node->type->entity->label();` is a bit more graceful maybe? I'm not sure there's a shorter version currently

Comment: Also works in twig template: {{ node.type.entity.label }}

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The following code works, as pointed out from [@Clive](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/199559/how-do-i-get-the-node-type-label-from-a-node-object#comment241144_199559).

```
$type_name = $node->type->entity->label();
```

Comment: Works for me. Thanks

Comment: For anyone who needs to mock this, there's some magic going on.  A magic __get method in ContentEntityBase which looks for type in it's fieldDefinitions array.  The BaseFieldDefinition type is then returned as part of an EntityReferenceFieldItemList. Then another magic __get method in its base class FieldItemList, gets the first (and I think only) element of the list, which is an EntityReferenceItem, it then calls its own __get method to get the 'entity' property, which pulls an EntityReference from its own 'properties' array. Finally the label function is called from the EntityBase class.

Answer (score 14):

In case you need the node type machine name in Twig template:

```
{{ node.getType }}
```

Answer (score 10):

If you want the label in twig

```
{{ node.type.entity.label }}
```

Answer (score 7):

Try this code.

```
use Drupal\node\Entity\NodeType;

$types = NodeType::loadMultiple();
$bundle = $node->bundle(); 
$type_name = $types[$bundle]->label();
```

Comment: That loads all node types just to get the label of one. a bit inefficient, better to just load the one you want.

Comment: Agree! It's just base on code of @No Sssweat.

Comment: @Berdir thx for pointing that out. I don't want to chameleon the question, so I will leave this as the accepted answer. I am using the code in my own answer instead.

Answer (score 2):

There is a function for that

```
node_get_type_label($node);
```